# Core-icons icon not showing up as expected in Polymer 1.2.1

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer 1.2.1
I have imported core-icons in elements.html as follows

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icons/social-icons.html">
```

I have the following code :

```
 <paper-icon-button icon="social:person" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
```

inside a custom Polymer element. However, the icon does not show up.

The template section markup looks like this

Hello World

If I change the icon attribute to home, as below, it shows up

Answer (score 1):

The element core-icons is deprecated. Have you considered using the new iron-icons? (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons)
Here is the list of icons available: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?view=demo:demo/index.html, including social icons.